# Shortest Proof of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theroem ( 5 lines) without using Fatou's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If  {$G_n$} is a sequence of bounded measurable functions  and $ | G_n | \le M $ where M is a positive real number $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} G_n =F$ on a bounded measurable set E , $\epsilon> 0 $
Let $A_n =$ { $x : |G_m(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$} whenever  $m \ge n$

and let $B_n =$ { $x : |G_n(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$}

Then $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}\subseteq B_{n+1}\subseteq E   , \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*( A_n) = \mu^*( E) $  according to [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772057/outer-measure-of-a-nested-sequence-of-non-measurable-sets)
Then$\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*( B_n) =\mu^*( E)  , \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*( B_n^C) =0  $

$B_n$ is measurable so its outer and inner measures are equal

$ \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}  | \int_{E}(G_n -F) | \le\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_{B_n}|(G_n -F)|+\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_{B_n^C}|(G_n -F)| \le \epsilon M$

The condition that each $ G_n $ is bounded by M can be relaxed to uniform integrability of {$ G_n $}.

Comment: Are you asking for verification of your proof?

Comment: Yes .Please do tell if you find a flaw.

Comment: I haven't seen a proof with outer measures, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @walkar. $B_n$ is measurable so its outer and inner measures are equal

Comment: $A_n$ doesn't appear to be well defined.  You have it set to an infinitude of (possibly distinct) sets for each choice of $m \geq n$.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is used before being defined.  ("Let $\varepsilon > 0$" would do.)  $E$ is used before being introduced or defined.  (If you intend to reuse notation from the theorem statement, you need to state the theorem.)  I don't understand what you mean by "$E \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu^*(A_n)$" because (1) $\mu^*$ is undefined and (2) I don't know what the product of a set and a number is.

Comment: @Eric Towera. I made some corrections.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend avoiding naming functions with capital letters, except in the context of operators. Standard run of the mill functions are usually denoted with lower case letters. It is much easier for people to differentiate sets and functions this way. Also you have $F_m$ and $G_m$ floating around but you never defined $F_m$. As is, your post is fairly difficult to read through for these reasons.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I made corrections.

Comment: I gave a proof of the theorem used in my proof http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772057/outer-measure-of-a-nested-sequence-of-non-measurable-sets/1775641#1775641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  {$G_n$} is a sequence of bounded measurable functions  and $ | G_n | \le M $ where M is a positive real number $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} G_n =F$ on a bounded measurable set E , $\epsilon> 0 $
Let $A_n =$ { $x : |G_m(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$} whenever  $m \ge n$

and let $B_n =$ { $x : |G_n(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$}

Then $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}\subseteq B_{n+1}\subseteq E   , \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*( A_n) = \mu^*( E) $  according to [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772057/outer-measure-of-a-nested-sequence-of-non-measurable-sets)
Then$\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*( B_n) =\mu^*( E)  , \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \mu^*( B_n^C) =0  $

$B_n$ is measurable so its outer and inner measures are equal

$ \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}  | \int_{E}(G_n -F) | \le\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_{B_n}|(G_n -F)|+\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_{B_n^C}|(G_n -F)| \le \epsilon M$

The condition that each $ G_n $ is bounded by M can be relaxed to uniform integrability of {$ G_n $}.

Comment: Your proof is false in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: On $(0,1),$ let $f_n(x) = n^2x^n.$ Then each $f_n$ is bounded on $(0,1),$ and $f_n \to 0$ pointwise on $(0,1).$ But $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\, dx = n^2/(n+1) \to \infty,$ while $\int_0^1 0\, dx = 0.$

Comment: Not a counter example.Your $ f_n $ is not bounded by any real number nor is your {$f_n$} uniformly integrable.

Comment: I addressed the result you first claimed, which was in error. So a better comment from you, I think, would have been to admit the error.

Comment: I gave a proof of the theorem used in the proof : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772057/outer-measure-of-a-nested-sequence-of-non-measurable-sets/1775641#1775641