# Does the continuity from below hold for inner measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

In class, I have learned that Lebesgue outer measure has upward measure continuity. That is, if $A_n$ increase to $A$, $m^*(A_n)$ converges to $m^*(A)$ even though $A_n$ is not measurable.
I am wondering whether the same result holds for the inner measure. Is there any counterexample where $m_*(A_n)$  doesn't converge to  $m_*(A)$ with $A_n$ increasing to $A$ ?

Comment: See my comment to [Continuity Properties of Lebesgue Measure violated by non-measurable sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3431521/13130) for the strongest results I know (for Lebesgue inner and outer measure). I don't have time now to give an appropriate answer your question, but depending on what kind of comments/answers you get, I might return when I'm less busy and provide a proof for what I gave in that comment and give counterexamples to illustrate the sharpness of the statements.

Comment: It seems natural the inner measure is continuous from above. However, what about the continuity from below? A counterexample must be a sequence of non-measurable sets, which agonizes me a lot.

Comment: **Hint:** Letting $P \subseteq [0,1]$ be a Vital nonmeasurable set, make some changes to the following using the fact that [$m_*(P)=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1211067/13130) Enumerate the rationals in the unit interval as ${\mathbb Q}\cap[0,1]=\{r_1,\,r_2,\,\ldots\}$ and let $A_n=\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}(P+r_k).$ Note that for each positive integer $n$ we have $m^*(A_n)\geq m^*(P+r_n)=m^*(P).$ Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}m^*(A_n) \geq m^*(P) > 0.$ However, since $A_n \searrow \emptyset,$ we have $m^*(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n)=m^*(\emptyset)=0.$

Comment: Sorry for not getting your hint. I am looking for an increasing sequence of sets. Why would we look at $A_n$?

Comment: Note that I said "make some changes". Consider the sets $B_n = [0,1] - A_n.$

Comment: Got it. I think I should use $m([0,1])$=$m_*(B_n)+m^*(A_n)$ here. Thanks a lot.